# VLC could not read the file input/output error

Tags: vlc

I am having a CD which was copy protected. I gave to my friend, she copied the contents somehow. She said she copied .DAT file. Now when I insert the CD, I won't see the tilte of CD and it is not playing. It is giving the below error.

VLC could not read the file input/output error

Can anyone tell me, how to make this CD normal.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that VLC knows it's playing a VCD and its using a 'CD' device (not a 'DVD').

In VLC just go to 'Media' -> 'Open Disc', then select 'SVCD/VCD' and change the Device setting to the appropriate 'CDROM' device.

Hit 'Play' and you should have more success.

Or this should help also:

media>open(advanced)>disk>svcd/vcd>disc Device- change to /dev/